# non static method write cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante em [android](/questions/tagged/android) e em programação no geral, estava seguindo uma vídeo aula para gravar uma string em um arquivo txt, quando me deparei com o seguinte erro:

> Error:(49, 31) error: non-static method write(String) cannot be
>   referenced from a static context

Eu chequei e o código me parecia estar correto perante ao do professor.

Eis o código java:

```
package minhasanotacoes.cursoandroid.com.minhaanotacoes;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import static java.io.OutputStreamWriter.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText texto;
    private ImageView botaoSalvar;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        texto =  findViewById(R.id.texto_ID);
        botaoSalvar = findViewById(R.id.botao_salvar_id);

        botaoSalvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String textoDigitado = texto.getText().toString();


            }
        });
    }

    private void gravarNoArquivo(String texto) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("anotacao.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
            OutputStreamWriter.write(texto);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.v("MainActivity", e .toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu erro está em:

```
private void gravarNoArquivo(String texto) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("anotacao.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        OutputStreamWriter.write(texto);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Log.v("MainActivity", e .toString());
    }
}
```

Você está chamando o método `write` em `OutputStreamWriter`, deveria ser `outputStreamWriter.write(texto)`

Chamando assim: `OutputStreamWriter.write(texto);`, não vai dar certo, a classe [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) não possui o método estático `write` com essa assinatura, por isso o erro, você deve chamar o método no objeto que você acaba de criar